# Java: Expanding TicTacToe to an N*N board, how to determine a line of 3?

Tags: java, dynamic, size, tic-tac-toe

As a self-learning experience I have built a 3x3 TicTacToe game. Now I want to expand that game to a N x N size board. This presents me a problem when determining the winning condition.

The original game used a array to look for a winning condition:

```
private final int[][] win = new int[][] {
        {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, //horizontal
        {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, //vertical
        {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}             //diagonal
};
```

And in the ActionListener:

```
// Check the win array for 3-in-a-line condition.
        for(int i = 0; i<=7; i++){
            if( b[win[i][0]].getText().equals( b[win[i][1]].getText() ) && // A == B
                b[win[i][1]].getText().equals( b[win[i][2]].getText() ) && // B == C
                !b[win[i][0]].getText().equals("")){                       // Not empty 

                b[win[i][0]].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                b[win[i][1]].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                b[win[i][2]].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                gameOver = true;
                System.out.println("WIN WIN WIN");
```

With the game expanding to N x N size, I can't have a fixed array for determining the winning conditions.

I will need some procedure to determine if there 3 (or more) in a line. So how would you approach this? Is there a smarter way to do this rather than check all the squares closest to the placed in? (North+South, East+West, N+N, E+E, S+S, W+W, NE+SW, NW+SE, NE+NE, NW+NW, SE+SE, SW+SW) and try and filter out all the PointerExceptions?

Check the entire board each time and control the indexes of the for-loops not to go out-of-bounds?

Either solution feels like nightmare to code. Anyone have a smarter approach to this problem?

Adding the entire program for reference:

```
package heniv181;


import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


/**
 *  @author Henrik
 *  Also code by John (john@codecall.net) http://forum.codecall.net/topic/36472-javatutorial-tic-tac-toe/
 *  
 */
public class TicTacToeBig extends JFrame
                       implements ActionListener {

    private int size = 5;
    private JButton[] b = new JButton[size*size];
    private int turn = 0;


    private final int[][] win = new int[][] {
            {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, //horizontal
            {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, //virticle
            {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}             //diagonal
    };                               


    //  Constructor
    public TicTacToeBig(){   

        setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocation(200, 200);
        setVisible(true);  

        setLayout(new GridLayout(size,size));

        for(int i=0; i < size*size; i++){
            b[i] = new JButton();
            b[i].setText("");
            b[i].addActionListener(this);
            b[i].setActionCommand( Integer.toString(i));       
            add(b[i]);

        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){      


        TicTacToeBig t = new TicTacToeBig();

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        String sign;
        boolean gameOver = false;

        //  Whos turn is it? X's or O's? 
        turn++;
        if(turn % 2 == 0)
            sign="X";
        else
            sign="O";

        // Set X or O on the button pressed.
        JButton press = (JButton)ae.getSource();
        press.setText(sign);
        press.setEnabled(false);
        gameOver = checkWin(press);



        /* Check the win array for 3-in-a-line condition.
        for(int i = 0; i<=7; i++){
            if( b[win[i][0]].getText().equals( b[win[i][1]].getText() ) && // A == B
                b[win[i][1]].getText().equals( b[win[i][2]].getText() ) && // B == C
                !b[win[i][0]].getText().equals("")){                       // Not empty 

                b[win[i][0]].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                b[win[i][1]].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                b[win[i][2]].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                gameOver = true;
                System.out.println("WIN WIN WIN");

            }   

        }*/

        //End game if winning conditon is true or no more turns.
        if(gameOver){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulation!\n" + sign + " have won!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(turn>=(size*size) ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "To bad!\n No winners. ");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    public boolean checkWin(JButton j){

        //HHmmmm..........

        int index = Integer.valueOf( j.getActionCommand() );

        System.out.println(index);   



        if((index+1) % size == 0 || (index+1) % size == 1)
            System.out.println("R or L Edge.");

        if(index-size < 0 || index+size > b.length-1)
            System.out.println("U or D Edge");

        //check right and left
            //check if point is on right or left edge
            //compare index-1   L
            //compare index+1   R

        //check up and down
            //check if point is on top or bottom edge
            //compare index - size  D   
            //compare index + size  U

        //check diagonals
            //check if point is on edge
            //compare index - size -1   UL
            //compare index - size +1   UR
            //compare index + size -1   DL  
            //compare index + size +1   DR



        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does a player win n x n tic-tac-toe when they get n in a row?

Comment: Stick with your 3x3 and generalize the number 3 out of your logic, replacing it with a variable. Then when you get that working, change the value of variable from 3 to whatever you want it to be.

Comment: If you really are only looking for a row of three no matter what N is, then your test is going to be expensive.

Comment: Not possible, the original has a fixed array containing ALL win conditions. I cannot do that if the player wants a 64x64 board.

Comment: Your grid squares (or whatever they're called) need to be boolean instead of hard coded numbers. If all diagonal grid boxes are true for O or X then you declare a win accordingly. Or false. You will have to think the logic you want to put in it.

Comment: nickecarlo, what type of data that is in the array is really irrelevant to this problem i think.

Comment: Edit: The win condition is of course a row, column or diagonal or 3. Changed the title.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this would be at the time you are adding the new mark to the game board.

Then, you just need to test the row, column, and diagonals that include the current cell rather than testing the entire board.

Comment: Thx Jay, the problem with this is the NullPointer Exceptions, and the problems around the edges.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the calculations for dimensionality yourself. Here's a start. It creates a one-dimensional array for the board but provides access to pick a cell in that array from an n-dimensional coordinate.

I have put no work into range checking or tracking rows and columns.

I have chosen `int` for the array with the aim of using `0 = Empty`, `1 = O` and `-1 = X`. You can then add up the values in each row and see if it comes out to +/- `s` to see if someone has won.

```
public class TicTacToe {
  // Each piece.
  static final int Empty = 0;
  static final int X = 1;
  static final int O = -1;
  // A Board is a number of cells.

  static class Board {
    // Dimensions.
    final int d;
    // Size.
    final int s;
    // The board is just an array of ints.
    final int[] board;

    // Create board of the specified size.
    public Board(int d, int s) {
      this.d = d;
      this.s = s;
      /* E.G.
       * 3 * 3 = 9 cells in a 2-D board.
       * 3 * 3 * 3 = 27 rows in a 3-D board.
       */
      board = new int[(int) Math.pow(d, s)];
    }

    void setPiece(int[] coords, int value) {
      board[getLoc(coords)] = value;
    }

    boolean won() {
      boolean won = false;
      // For each piece.
      for (int p = 0; p < board.length; p++) {
        // Where is this piece.
        int[] coords = getCoords(p);
        // No point in checking empty squares.
        int piece = getPiece(coords);
        if (piece != Empty) {
          // First check non-diagonals.
          int [] check;
          // Vary each dimension from 0 to 3.
          for (int i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
            // Back to there.
            check = Arrays.copyOf(coords, coords.length);
            // The sum across this dimension.
            int sum = 0;
            // By the size of the board.
            for (int j = 0; j < s; j++) {
              check[i] = j;
              sum += getPiece(check);
            }
            if (sum == piece * s) {
              // A line adds up!
              return true;
            }
          }
        }

      }
      return won;
    }

    int getPiece(int[] coords) {
      /*
       * Say [1,1] is the center of a 3x3 board so it is at 4 in the array.
       * 
       * i.e. the array is:
       * 
       * 0 - [0,0]
       * 1 - [0,1]
       * 2 - [0,2]
       * 3 - [1,0]
       * 4 - [1,1] - *
       * 5 - [1,2]
       * 6 - [2,0]
       * 7 - [2,1]
       * 8 - [2,2]
       * 
       * So (1 * 3) + 1 = 4
       * 
       * But [1,1,1], being the center of a 3x3x3 board must be at 13!
       * 
       * So ((1 * 3) + 1) * 3) + 1 = 13
       */
      return board[getLoc(coords)];
    }

    // Returns the location in the array where the cell at this coordinate is.
    private int getLoc(int[] coords) {
      // Where this piece is in the array.
      int loc = coords[0];
      for (int i = 1; i < coords.length; i++) {
        // Add in each dimension of coordinate.
        loc = loc * s + coords[i];
      }
      return loc;
    }

    // Reverse the getLoc by taking a loc and rolling it into a coordinates.
    private int[] getCoords(int loc) {
      // It must be that wide.
      int[] coords = new int[d];
      // Work backwards from the end.
      for (int i = coords.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // Take remainder.
        coords[i] = loc % s;
        // Divide.
        loc /= s;
      }
      return coords;
    }

  }

  private void test() {
    System.out.println("Board(2,3) - piece[1,1] @ " + new Board(2, 3).getLoc(new int[]{1, 1}));
    System.out.println("Board(3,3) - piece[1,1,1] @ " + new Board(3, 3).getLoc(new int[]{1, 1, 1}));
    System.out.println("Board(2,3) - loc[8] @ " + Arrays.toString(new Board(2, 3).getCoords(8)));
    System.out.println("Board(2,3) - loc[0] @ " + Arrays.toString(new Board(2, 3).getCoords(0)));
    System.out.println("Board(3,3) - loc[13] @ " + Arrays.toString(new Board(3, 3).getCoords(13)));
    Board board = new Board(3,3);
    boolean won = board.won();
    System.out.println("Won: " + won);
    // Set a row.
    board.setPiece(new int[]{0, 1, 1}, X);
    board.setPiece(new int[]{1, 1, 1}, X);
    board.setPiece(new int[]{2, 1, 1}, X);
    // Should have a win.
    won = board.won();
    System.out.println("Won: " + won);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      new TicTacToe().test();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
  }

}
```

Correctly prints:

```
Board(2,3) - piece[1,1] @ 4
Board(3,3) - piece[1,1,1] @ 13
Board(2,3) - loc[8] @ [2, 2]
Board(2,3) - loc[0] @ [0, 0]
Board(3,3) - loc[13] @ [1, 1, 1]
Won: false
Won: true
```

Note that this does not as yet check diagonals - you will have to do that yourself.

Comment: Thank you OldCurmudgeon. However it's the "range checking and tracking rows and columns" I'm pondering over. I can figure out how to check adjacent squares, but I don't know how to handle cases where I hit an edge on the board. And I'm really only worried about 2 dimensions.

Comment: @heniv181 - I've added a `won` method - it does not check diagonals, that is for you to work out.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your win function (). You loop through the entire board on each check, you skip the empty cells... then you seem to sum ALL(?) the pieces in one row..... I don't understand how you can tell if you have 3 identical pieces next to each other.... Thnx for the answer though.

Comment: @heniv181 - It is not designed to be the most efficient method, just **a** method. It certainly checks more than it needs to but it does seem to get it right. Using 1/0/-1 for each X/Blank/O I can add up all of the values in a row/column and if the row is all of the same piece the sum will be the length of the row (3 for a 3x3 board). Using coordinates I just vary each dimension of the coordinate from 0 to board width to track a straight line. E.g. [0,0],[0,1],[0,2] and [0,0],[1,0],[2,0] are the two lines passing through [0,0] on a 3x3 board.

Comment: Hmmm..... sorry for being unclear. But the win condition is a row/col/diag of 3 in any size of board. So a row of _OXXXO in a 6x6 board is still a win.

Comment: This code demonstrates how you can work in any number of dimensions and any board size and still walk in any direction in any dimension through the structure. I think you will have to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Henrik,

The problem that you are having with hitting the edges is not inherent to testing from the last played position.  It is possible to do this if you are careful and program iteratively.

Here is a partial solution for your game.  It is not optimal, and does not test for diagonals that slope upward from left to right.  But, it seems to work - cleanup and understanding is up to you.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
* @author JayDM
*         Loosely based on code provide by Henrik
* 
*/
public class TicTacToeBig extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int size = 5;
private JButton[][] b;
private int turn = 0;

// Constructor
public TicTacToeBig() {
    setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 300);
    setLocation(200, 200);
    setVisible(true);

    b = new JButton[size][size];

    setLayout(new GridLayout(size, size));

    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            System.out.println("Adding button for position: " + row + ", " + col);

            b[row][col] = new JButton();
            b[row][col].setText("_");
            b[row][col].addActionListener(this);
            b[row][col].setActionCommand(row + "," + col);
            add(b[row][col]);
        }
    }

    invalidate();
    validate();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String sign;

    // Whos turn is it? X's or O's?
    turn++;

    if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        sign = "O";
    } else {
        sign = "X";
    }

    // Set X or O on the button pressed.
    JButton press = (JButton) ae.getSource();

    press.setText(sign);
    press.setEnabled(false);

    // End game if winning conditon is true or no more turns.
    if (checkWin(press)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations!\n" + sign + " has won!");

        System.exit(0);
    } else if (turn >= (size * size)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "To bad!\n No winners. ");

        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public boolean checkWin(JButton j) {
    String position[] = j.getActionCommand().split(",");

    int row = Integer.parseInt(position[0]);
    int col = Integer.parseInt(position[1]);

    System.out.println(b[row][col].getText() + " played @ " + row + ", " + col);

    String winner = b[row][col].getText() + b[row][col].getText() + b[row][col].getText();
    String field;

    // row
    field = "";

    for (int testCol = Math.max(0, col - 2); testCol < Math.min(size, col + 3); testCol++) {
        field += b[row][testCol].getText();
    }

    System.out.println("Testing row field: " + field);

    if (field.contains(winner)) {
        System.out.println("Row winner!");

        return true;
    }

    // col
    field = "";

    for (int testRow = Math.max(0, row - 2); testRow < Math.min(size, row + 3); testRow++) {
        field += b[testRow][col].getText();
    }

    System.out.println("Testing column field: " + field);

    if (field.contains(winner)) {
        System.out.println("Column winner!");

        return true;
    }

    // diagonals
    int lowerBound = 0;
    int upperBound = 0;

    // diagonal down
    field = "";

    // top left
    lowerBound = - Math.min(2, Math.min(col, row));

    // bottom right
    upperBound = Math.min(3, size - Math.max(row, col));

    System.out.println("Bounds: " + lowerBound + ", " + upperBound);

    for (int offset = lowerBound; offset < upperBound; offset++) {
        field += b[row + offset][col + offset].getText();
    }

    System.out.println("Testing diagonal down field: " + field);

    if (field.contains(winner)) {
        System.out.println("Diagonal down winner!");

        return true;
    }

    // diagonal up
    field = "";

    // bottom left
    // lowerBound = ?????????????;
    lowerBound = 0;

    // top right
    // upperBound = ?????????????;
    upperBound = 0;

    System.out.println("Bounds: " + lowerBound + ", " + upperBound);

    for (int offset = lowerBound; offset < upperBound; offset++) {
        // field += b[row +/- offset][col +/- offset].getText();
    }

    System.out.println("Testing diagonal up field: " + field);

    if (field.contains(winner)) {
        System.out.println("Diagonal up winner!");

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    TicTacToeBig t = new TicTacToeBig();
}
}
```

Comment: Here is a simple description of how this is working.  It creates a string of up to five characters long extending two characters each way (plus the new cell in the center).  Then, it checks that string for three in a row.  The boundaries are set by checking the current position against the left/top edge (0) and the right/bottom edge (size).  Rows are easy. Columns are easy. The downward diagonal is fairly easy. The upward diagonal is fairly difficult (but you should be able to figure it out).

Comment: The program could be optimized a bit on diagonals by checking whether or not it is even possible to get three in a row (are there at least going to be three cells in a row in the diagonal?).  And you could even 'cheat' by catching the exceptions when you try to go past the edges rather than setting boundaries.

Comment: But, you should close this question so we can all stop paying attention to it.